BigQuery Workflow Notebook Error: "Unable to generate link to the notebook output or the bucket which contains it"
I’m running a notebook on BigQuery as part of a Dataform workflow. My goal is to analyze content using TF-IDF to find internal link opportunities, but when I execute the notebook, I encounter the following error:
Error Message:

Failure reason: Error encountered during cell execution.
Notebook output: Unable to generate link to the notebook output or the bucket which contains it.

Here’s the code I’m working with:
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

df = pd.read_csv('content.csv')

df.head()

def find_internal_link_opportunities(df):
    contents = df['content'].tolist()
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(contents)
    vectors = vectorizer.toarray()
    csim = cosine_similarity(vectors)
    return csim

csim = find_internal_link_opportunities(df)

def display_link_opportunities(df, csim, threshold=0.5):
    results = []

    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        similar_indices = [i for i, score in enumerate(csim[idx]) if score > threshold and i != idx]

        if similar_indices:
            for i in similar_indices:
                results.append({
                    'url': row['Address'],
                    'sim_url': df.iloc[i]['Address'],
                    'sim_ratio': f"{csim[idx][i]:.2f}"
                })

    # Create a DataFrame to display results in a table format
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['url', 'sim_url', 'sim_ratio'])

    return result_df

final_res = display_link_opportunities(df, csim, threshold=0.2)

I’ve tried the following:
Saving the output in a CSV file.
Ensuring I have all the required access and permissions.
Setting the correct bucket as the active storage.
Despite these efforts, I still encounter the same error: “Unable to generate link to the notebook output or the bucket which contains it.”
Has anyone encountered this issue before or knows how to fix it?
Additional Info:
The notebook is part of a Dataform workflow in BigQuery.
I have granted the necessary permissions for bucket access.
I am able to run the notebook but cannot access the output or logs from the notebook.
Any help or insights would be appreciated!

Which statement is producing the error?

BigQuery doesn't indicate where the error occurred.
